# Multiplication and Concataning results in Dart

Tags: printing, for-loop, dart

I'm new in Dart language but I still working on ! I got this problem, I want to calculate the table of multiplication of : 14.

So basicly, i want to get this results:
14,28,42,56,70,84,98,112,126, etc etc to 1400

My function work, when I print my result. But I can't paste the results in a div.

There is my .dart :

```
main() {    
  var numero2 = 14;
  var multiplication = 0;
  var element02 = query('#exercice02');   
  for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    multiplication = numero2 * i;
    print(multiplication); 
  }
  //element02.text = multiplication;

}
```

And in my html i got :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HelloWorld</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="HelloWorld.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <p class="question">Exercice 02 : 100 x 14 : <span id="exercice02"></span></p>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="web/HelloWorld.dart"></script>
    <script src="https://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Actually, I dont know how to concatane the results, I try as you can see the : element02.text = multiplication; in FOR, but it destroy it, and then I try the += and they are multiplicating together and I only have 1 result at the end.

Some one can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want the results to be displayed? Like: `14, 28, 42`?

**test.dart**

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 14; i <= 1400; i += 14) {
    results.add(i.toString());
  }

  var element = query('#container');
  element.text = Strings.join(results, ', ');
}
```

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="test.dart"></script>
    <script src="https://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:

> 14, 28, 42, 56, 70, 84, 98, 112, 126, 140, 154, 168, 182, 196, 210,
>   224, 238, 252, 266, 280, 294, 308, 322, 336, 350, 364, 378, 392, 406,
>   420, 434, 448, 462, 476, 490, 504, 518, 532, 546, 560, 574, 588, 602,
>   616, 630, 644, 658, 672, 686, 700, 714, 728, 742, 756, 770, 784, 798,
>   812, 826, 840, 854, 868, 882, 896, 910, 924, 938, 952, 966, 980, 994,
>   1008, 1022, 1036, 1050, 1064, 1078, 1092, 1106, 1120, 1134, 1148,
>   1162, 1176, 1190, 1204, 1218, 1232, 1246, 1260, 1274, 1288, 1302,
>   1316, 1330, 1344, 1358, 1372, 1386, 1400

Comment: Thank you, it answer perfectly what I wanted to do !